# Counter for List in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a list like this.

```
listt =[[' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.5','91.9','91.9','91.9','92.55','92.55','92.1','93.3','93.3 '],
    [' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.6','91.6','92.85','92.85','92.85','92.85','92.3','92.3','92.1','92.1','94.1',],
    [' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.5','91.5','91.65','91.65','91.5','92.9','92.9 '],
    [' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.85','91.85','91.6','91.85','91.85','92.55','92.4','92.4','93.7','93.7','93.35','93.35 '],
    [' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.6','91.6','91.3','91.3','92.75','92.75','92.15','92.15','93.15','93.15','92.9']]
```

I want to print the daily number of unique measurements in descending order based on date.

My expected result is

[image: expected output]

I am using Counter. But it does not make group by.

```
c = collections.Counter(daily_weights)
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. What, **exactly** is your expected output? `Counter` requires that whatever you are trying to count be hashable. List items are not hashable. How to get around this is hard to say because, again, it isn't clear what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need Counter for this task. Just do:

```
import pprint
from operator import itemgetter

listt = [[' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 ', ' 91.5', '91.9', '91.9', '91.9', '92.55', '92.55', '92.1', '93.3', '93.3 '],
         [' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 ', ' 91.6', '91.6', '92.85', '92.85', '92.85', '92.85', '92.3', '92.3', '92.1',
          '92.1', '94.1', ],
         [' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 ', ' 91.5', '91.5', '91.65', '91.65', '91.5', '92.9', '92.9 '],
         [' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 ', ' 91.85', '91.85', '91.6', '91.85', '91.85', '92.55', '92.4', '92.4', '93.7',
          '93.7', '93.35', '93.35 '],
         [' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 ', ' 91.6', '91.6', '91.3', '91.3', '92.75', '92.75', '92.15', '92.15', '93.15',
          '93.15', '92.9']]

# count number of unique measurements
counts = ((head, len(set(tail))) for head, *tail in listt)

# sort the list in descending order based on the count of unique measurements
res = sorted(counts, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
[(' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 ', 8),
 (' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 ', 7),
 (' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 ', 6),
 (' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 ', 6),
 (' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 ', 5)]
```

The [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
# count number of unique measurements
counts = ((head, len(set(tail))) for head, *tail in listt)
```

will count the number of unique measurements per day. Then just [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) using this number in descending order.

```
# sort the list in descending order based on the count of unique measurements
res = sorted(counts, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use `pandas` here. It is more readable, maintainable and scalable. Plus it has inner support for datetime if you ever wanted to change the format of your date column.

```
import pandas as pd 

l1 =[[' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.5','91.9','91.9','91.9','92.55','92.55','92.1','93.3','93.3 '],
    [' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.6','91.6','92.85','92.85','92.85','92.85','92.3','92.3','92.1','92.1','94.1',],
    [' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.5','91.5','91.65','91.65','91.5','92.9','92.9 '],
    [' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.85','91.85','91.6','91.85','91.85','92.55','92.4','92.4','93.7','93.7','93.35','93.35 '],
    [' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 ',' 91.6','91.6','91.3','91.3','92.75','92.75','92.15','92.15','93.15','93.15','92.9']]

df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
df.columns = ["date"] + ["M{}".format(i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns))]

df = df.set_index(["date"])
res=df.nunique(axis=1)
res.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)

print(res)
```

output will be:

```
date
 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00     8
 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00     7
 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00     6
 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00     6
 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00     5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Using pandas is not a best practice, and is not more readable (you need to know pandas for understanding the solution)